# How does Composer compile the "optimize-autoloader" classmap?

Tags: php, composer-php

What exactly goes in that list?

How does it know what classes are in use without a full-blown static analysis of the code?

And why does it even read the files? Isn't the purpose of PSR4 avoiding this specifically?

Comment: Could you please undelete your [CSS Grid question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800711/whats-the-flex-basis-auto-flex-grow-equivalent-for-css-grids)? It's interesting.

Answer (score 3):

Composer packages can define their autoloader mappings, for example:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyVendor\MyPackage": "src/"
    }
}
```

Composer collates all of these definitions and generates classmap autoloader files from them.

Reference: https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/0c912d6/src/Composer/Autoload/AutoloadGenerator.php#L158-L184

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was looking for a more "plain english" explanation :P Composer does a lot of guesswork, it looks for classes in files by using regexps (and it's really clumsy at it) and I don't understand why. Shouldn't it just map filesystem to php namespace?

Comment: Well, that’s what PSR-4 does. I expect non PSR conformance would be as you described, but hopefully is becoming deprecated